# How to input values and add them to a dictionary within a dictionary by using raw_input in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, raw-input

How do I get this code:

```
ans = raw_input('Enter Amount of Players: ').lower()
if ans == '2':
    a = raw_input('What is Player 1 named:')
    b = raw_input('What is Player 2 named:')
    cf={a:{}, b:{}}
    p1 = raw_input('What is Player 1 city named:')  
    p2 = raw_input('What is Player 2 city named:') 
    cf[a[p1]] = '50'
    cf[b[p2]] = '50'
```

To produce something like this if i input 'matt' for player 1, 'nick' for player 2, 'nyc' for player 1 city, and 'la' for player 2 city:

```
 {'matt':{'nyc':50}, 'nick':{'la':50}}
```

Instead of an error code?

Comment: `cf[a][p1]` rather than `cf[a[p1]]`? Also, lowercasing a numeric input seems just a little strange.

Comment: That makes it work thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 cf.__getitem__(a).__setitem__(p1,50)
 cf.__getitem__(b).__setitem__(p2,50)
```

Comment: That's what `cf[a][p1] = 50` does - you almost never want to call those methods directly.